# what is the rank of the multiplication transformation $A$ if $AX=PX$ and $P$ has rank $m$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, transformation

Consider the vector space consisting of all linear transformations on a vector
space $V$, and let $A$ be the (left) multiplication transformation that sends each transformation $X$ on $V$ onto $PX$, where $P$ is some prescribed transformation on $V$.
If $P$ has rank $m$, what is the rank of $A$?

$Source$: Halmos Finite demensional vector space, Section 50 Rank and nullity, exercise #3

Now from the question, I think that means $AX=PX$.
If $P$ has rank $m$, then $A$ must have the same rank, $m$.

Am I right? I am quite sure I have miss something. I don't think Halmos would ask such a simple question.

Please can you help, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the question: we start with a vector space $V$. Then, we consider the vector space of all linear transformations from $V$ to $V$. To be clear, let's give this its own name, let's say $W$. (This space is normally denoted $\mathrm{End}(V)$, because it consists of endomorphisms of $V$.)

Again, just to be clear, each **element** of $W$ is a different linear transformation from $V$ to $V$.

Now, having chosen some specific $P:V\to V$, we consider a linear transformation $A:W\to W$. The rule defining $A$ is that when we input a linear transformation $X:V\to V$, we output the new linear transformation $PX:V\to V$, that is, the composition of the maps
$$V\xrightarrow{\;\;X\;\;}V\xrightarrow{\;\;P\;\;}V\\ 
\xrightarrow[PX]{\qquad\qquad\qquad}$$
The question is asking you what the rank of the linear transformation $A:W\to W$ is. To start with, you should understand that $\dim(W)=\dim(V)^2$ (think about the dimension of a space of $n\times n$ matrices).

Comment: thanks a lot for answering. The rank of $A$ is the dimension of the range of $A$ by definition, so the rank of $A$ is the dimension of $W$. now since $P$ has the rank $m$, so the range of $P$ has deminsion $m$, that is $V$ has demension $m$. so the rank of $A$ is $m^2$. Am I right?

Comment: The rank of a linear transformation **is** the dimension of its range, but the range is ***different*** than the codomain. [See this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain). So for example, if we consider the linear transformation $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by
$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_1,0,0)$$
the rank of $f$ is $1$, not $3$. Do you understand?

Comment: oh, sorry about that. yeah, I understand what you meant now. re-read the question. I noted that $A$ send $X$ *onto* $PX$, so the range of $A$ is the set of all the linear transformation $PX$, and we know $P$ has range with the dimension $m$. I am not sure how to continues from here, can you give a bit more hint?

Comment: Are you aware of the rank-nullity theorem? You can use the fact that
$$n^2=\dim(W)=\mathrm{rank}(A)+ \mathrm{nullity}(A)=\dim(\mathrm{range}(A)) +\dim(\mathrm{kernel}(A))$$
Can you figure out which linear transformations $X:V\to V$ have the property that $A(X)=PX$ is the zero linear transformation? Those $X$'s comprise the kernel of $A$.

Comment: yes, I am awared of the rank-nullity theorem. I believe $A$ is $1-1$ if and only if $nullity(A)$ is the set of the zero linear transformation. That means if $A$ is 1-1 then $PX$ is the zero linear transformation, and so the range of $PX$ (which also is the range of $P$) has only one element. I have think about this quite a while, still not sure which way i should go.it seems I go the wrong direction.

Comment: I recommend to try thinking about an example. Let $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, so that $W$ is the space of $2\times 2$ matrices (therefore $\dim(W)=4$), and let $P=\bigl[\begin{smallmatrix} 3 & 1\\ 6 & 2\end{smallmatrix}\bigr]$. Figure out which matrices $X=\bigl[\begin{smallmatrix} x_1 & x_2\\ x_3 & x_4\end{smallmatrix}\bigr]$ have the property that $PX=\bigl[\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\bigr]$. The collection of those $X$'s is the kernel of $A$, since it is the collection of elements of $W$ that $A$ sends to the zero element of $W$.

Comment: it looks there are infinitely many such $X$ exist, for example \begin{pmatrix}11\\-3 -3\\ \end{pmatrix} is one of then, and then any multiplication of this matrix also would give us $PX = 0$. sorry, i am really have not clue.

Comment: The goal is to find the dimension of the subspace
$$\mathrm{kernel}(A)=\{X\in W: PX=0\}$$
The dimension of $W$ is $4$, so you know that the dimension of $\mathrm{kernel}(A)$ is somewhere between $0$ and $4$. You'll want to figure out the conditions on the numbers $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ that are imposed by the statement that
$$PX=\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1\\ 6 & 2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & x_2\\ x_3 & x_4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: oh, so the statement would gives us two equation: $3x_1+x_3=0$, and $3x_2+x_4=0$. that means $x_3$ depends on $x_1$ and $x_4$ depends on $x_2$ or vice verse. so we only need two elements to form the base, so the dimension of $kernel(A)$ is 2. is that what I need to do? But then what's the rank of $P$ to do with the solution in the original question?

Comment: i think maybe is this: for the kernel of $A$ is $X$ send every vector to zero, so that $PX$ also send every vector to zero, so $kernel(A)=Kernel(PX)$, and since the rank of $P$ is $m$, the rank of $PX$ also is $m$. so $dim(W)=rank(PX)+nullity(PX)$ as well. so $nullity(A)=nullity(PX)=n^2-m$, and so $rank(A)=n^2-(n^2-m)=m$. is that right?

Comment: Unfortunately no, you're very confused. $A$ is a map from $W$ to $W$, whereas $X$ (and therefore $PX$) are maps from $V$ to $V$, so it makes no sense to say $\mathrm{kernel}(A)=\mathrm{kernel}(PX)$. To be honest, I think your best course of action right now is to review more fundamental concepts in linear algebra (and possibly the general facts about sets and functions).

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment. just could you tell me the solution for this question for now?